# Could the 2001 anthrax letter attacks been connected to the disclosure of Project Jefferson?

Tags: biology, 9-11, terrorism

[Project Jefferson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jefferson) was designed to reproduce a strain of genetically-modified anthrax isolated by Russian scientists during the 1990s. It was disclosed (together with [Project Bacchus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Bacchus), [Project Clear Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Clear_Vision)) in a September 4, 2001 article in The New York Times (see http://www.nytimes.com/2001/09/04/world/us-germ-warfare-research-pushes-treaty-limits.html).

Since the anthrax attacks happened after 9/11 both terror attacks were often connected. But could it be that the anthrax attacks had nothing to do with 9/11? Instead somebody felt threatened by the disclosure of the biological weapons programs by the New York Times and started the anthrax attacks quite independently not because of 9/11, but instead because of 9/4?

Comment: This is a question of motivations of an unknown individual. We can't ever prove motivations using empirical evidence.

Comment: But couldn't some evidence at least make the proposed scenario sound less or more likely?

Comment: What sort of evidence, on each side, would it take to convince you to click "Accept"?